# Where does the notation $S^n$ for the $n$-dimensional sphere originate?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, notation

Just as in the title. The notation is somewhat surprising in its use of a superscript rather than a subscript, but I gather there is a history of using $M^n$ to refer to an $n$-dimensional manifold. Still, it is perhaps a bit awkward in leading us to say things like "$S^1 \times S^1$ is not isomorphic to $S^2$". The notation could perhaps be understood in the context of a smash product, but this is likely anachronistic.

Anyway, enough speculation. The question is simple: where does the use of $S^n$ to denote the $n$-dimensional sphere originate?

Comment: Have you checked Poincare's Analysis Situs? If so, and if Poincare uses that notation, does he give a pointer to prior use? Certainly by the time of Whitney's early papers it was commonplace, so if it doesn't appear in Poincare, you've narrowed it down to about 40 years.(A quick search of an online version of Poincare shows no use of it in Analysis Situs or supplements up through 1904.)

Answer (score -2):

We know that on one hand mathematical notation was developing evolutionarily, sometimes even ad hoc. On the other hand, mathematics is huge, requires a lot of notation, so much notation that it is hard to keep it short. Thus, at least in practice, consistency is often not attained across different times and domains.

Comment: Though I mused on notational inconsistencies as part of my curiosity, the question itself is not directly about them. The question only asks where this notation originated.

Comment: Relatedly, looking in the relevant section of "The History of Topology" https://books.google.com/books?id=7iRijkz0rrUC&pg=PA98&lpg=PA98&dq=history+of+smash+product+algebraic+topology&source=bl&ots=B_yerN-PrM&sig=P0JbK4SxLBnCuaqvD3U7IQC_iGQ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiqoI360IbQAhWGSyYKHQgkB_gQ6AEIOjAE#v=onepage&q=history%20of%20smash%20product%20algebraic%20topology&f=false

Comment: One finds that works of Hopf and Hurewicz in the 1920s and 1930s have been discussed in connection with building the (n+1)-sphere out of the n-sphere using the machinery of suspensions and smash products; whether they do that in the papers explicitly is worth looking in to.  Incidentally, the author refers to the n-sphere as $S_n$

Comment: I suggest to rewrite your answer including the content of your two comments.